# How to extract the remaining elements from std::sample

Tags: c++, std, sample

In the sample code [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) it shows cases how to use std::sample as shown below

```
std::string in = "hgfedcba", out;
std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                5, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
```

Possible output:

```
five random letters out of hgfedcba: gfcba
```

My question is not only I want `gfcba` I also want to extract the remaining elements that are the not sampled, e.g. `hed`. I know I can write a for loop to compare `in` and `out` to extract the  remaining elements, but I am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Why not extract all 8 characters and then copy the first 5 and the last 3 to two new strings?  Oh wait, that's `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @PaulSanders I can't believe I didn't discover `std::shuffle` while I was googling. Thanks. If you write down an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @PaulSanders - That's not a stable algorithm (unlike `std::sample`).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK, thanks. OP, do you care about the order of the characters in the output strings?

Comment: @PaulSanders the order doesn't matter for my target application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not concerned about the order of the characters in the output strings, then you can use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to randomise the input string and then copy the first 5 characters of the result to one output string and the last 3 to the other:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
    std::string in = "hgfedcba";

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g (rd ());
    std::shuffle (in.begin(), in.end(), g);

    std::string out5, out3;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        out5.push_back (in [i]);
    for (size_t i = 5; i < 8; ++i)
        out3.push_back (in [i]);
    
    std::cout << out5 << " " << out3;
}
```

Sample output:

```
cbhfd aeg
```